# relational PostgreSQL database from tab delimited

Tags: database, postgresql, import, relational-database

Trying to create a relational database from a healthcare related tsv in PostgreSQL. I created a database and created the 3 tables I need and that worked, so now I have three tables that I need to import the relevant data into.

I primarily work in Python, so I'm not great at SQL. I tried importing the entire text file just to see if it worked. It said it completed but when I use SELECT * FROM on any of the tables they're all blank.

So I then tried breaking up the tsv into the relevant columns of each table and saving them as csvs and importing them that way. That also didn't work.

I've tried googling around but have had no luck. I am on a mac if it matters.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the ```COPY``` command: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html You want to use the ```FROM``` variant

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!